# Creating consistant controllers on YII framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I'm using yii framework with action controller that every action in the controller make the same request but with minors changes. 
I'm using my controllers to call API (extension that I made).
And I would like to know how can I automatically set controllers to call API but with the specific values and attributes that is right for this controller.
So I wouldn't need to copy paste every code to all controllers.

I would like to know how to do the same thing with accesssControl filter (Config all rules I one class/function and all controller components).

Example:

```
      <?php
    public function actionLoadDataUser()
{


            //Set model
    $model = new User_DataForm;

    $function = "LoadDataUser";           //Set Method to set or get from (API)

            //Set model name
            $model_name = get_class($model);

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST[$model_name]))
    {       

                    $model->attributes = $_POST[$model_name];
                                        $response = Yii::app()-API->SendRawData($function,  $model->attributes);    // server and get response by function and data
                switch ($response)
                {
        case 'OK':
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('info','OK');
            $this->refresh();
        break;
        default: 
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('info','Error!');
            $this->refresh();
                }
    }

    // display the page
    $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model));
}




    public function actionLoadDataAdmin()
{

            //Set model
    $model = new Admin_DataForm;

    $function = "LoadDataAdmin";           //Set Method to set or get from (API)

            //Set model name
            $model_name = get_class($model);

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST[$model_name]))
    {       

                    $model->attributes = $_POST[$model_name];
                    $response = Yii::app()-API->SendRawData($function,  $model->attributes);    // server and get response by function and data
                switch ($response)
                {
        case 'OK':
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('info','OK');
            $this->refresh();
        break;
                    case 'NOT_ADMIN':
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('info','Access Denied');
            $this->refresh();
        break;
        default: 
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('info','Error!');
            $this->refresh();
                }
    }

    // display the page
    $this->render('admin', array('model'=>$model));
}
    ?>
```

Comment: can you give an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Access Control is it? so that only users grouped under specific roles have an access to that specific action?

Comment: try to give an example code. And if you want to access same action with different requests, you can have attribute from request and can follow with the same action.

Comment: As you can see, I have 2 action make the same call but slightly changes.
I think that the issue is the $response (user response notification) because every function I need to handle with it even it giving same results.

Comment: Would a Yii filter help at all? It's hard to tell exactly what you're after, but you can apply a filter against a bunch of actions all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: use one single action that will do your API calls depending of the parameters you pass to it.

```
public function actionLoadData()
{
    $modelName = $_POST['model'];
    $model     = new $modelName;
    $function  = $_POST['function'];

    if(isset($_POST[$modelName]))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST[$modelName];
        $response = Yii::app()->API->SendRawData($function,  $model->attributes);
        switch ($response)
        {
            case 'OK':
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('info', 'OK');
                $this->refresh();
                break;
            default: 
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('info', 'Error!');
                $this->refresh();
        }
    }

    $this->render($_POST['view'], array('model' => $model));
}
```

Note that this code isn't secure. Make sure you add some validations.

Comment: Thanks but, I have more controllers actions that $response depands by function, for example if the function is ActionLoadDataGuest:
`
       case 'OK':
                Yii::app()->ViewByRole(array('role' => 'guest'));
                break;
            default: 
               Yii::app()->ViewByRole->Error(array('role' => 'guest'));`

Comment: as I said all my action have minor changes. I have total of 80 actions that makes the same call. If I do what to tell I need to create 80 actions and another 70-80 function that make call with my changes. Its bad coding attitude

Comment: I see. I suggest using one single action, and to tell it what you need by passing it parameters. I'll update my code.

Comment: its still not what I'm wanted to do.
1. I can't pass vars by post because client can't cheat that to make they own request.
2. I still need to copy paste each action and change it to the specific function.

Comment: 1. That's why I said that you should validate the external data. 2. No you don't.

Comment: How can I change OK case result if the by function?

Comment: How many different responses can that API return? If they're not much, add more cases. If there's only flash messages to display, you can put them in an array and display them depending on the response. If things are more complicated than this, give anonymous functions a try.

Comment: I have same response but they do different things and this depending by function.

Comment: I'm thinking about replacing the switch with a function/method call. The function would be called `{$modelName.'_'.$response}()`. For example: `User_OK()`. And then creating these functions for each case. There may be a cleaner way though...